# Why is there no Green's function when no gauge is chosen (Linearized Gravity)

Tags: general-relativity, greens-functions, linearized-theory

I'm working on linearized gravity, and have come to the point where you need to choose a gauge to simplify the Einstein equation for the perturbative field.

Reading a paper, I came across the claim "The green's function does not exist without a gauge choice", but unfortunately nothing else was provided in support of the claim. I am wondering, is this because the equation without a gauge choice does not provide a unique solution, or is it something else?

Building on this, I am wondering, does the existence of a unique solution guarantee the existence of a green's function? Does it work the other way around as well?

Thanks

Comment: if you have a green's function, then that green's function will satisfy some gauge condition. The statment you quoted is just the contrapositive of this.

Comment: @ReidHayes    Any chance, if you have a minute,  if you could work your  first line of comment into a short answer, or even just give me a reference, even a Wikipedia statement. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The field equation in linearized gravity is

$$ \partial^2 h^{\mu \nu} + \partial^\mu \partial^\nu h - \partial_\lambda \partial^\nu h^{\mu \lambda} - \partial_\lambda \partial^\mu h^{\nu \lambda} - \eta^{\mu \nu} \partial^2 h + \eta^{\mu \nu} \partial_\lambda \partial_\sigma h^{\lambda \sigma} = - \kappa T^{\mu \nu}$$

You can write it in the form convenient for extracting Green's function:

$$L^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta} h_{\alpha \beta} = - \kappa T^{\mu \nu}$$

One would want to invert $L$, but the problem is that
$$\mathbf{det} (L) = 0$$
which is a manifestation of gauge invariance. $h^{\mu \nu}$ is not uniquely determined by $T^{\mu \nu}$. Different gauges give different values for $h^{\mu \nu}$ for the same $T^{\mu \nu}$.

Comment: Good answer! Exactly what I am looking for. Wondering if another, and easier route, to show that $h^{\mu\nu}$ is not uniquely determined by the equation is to show that a coordinate transformation $x' = x +\xi$ leads to a change in $h^{\mu\nu}$, but does not change the overall problem. My question is then, does the non-uniqueness of $h^{\mu\nu}$ imply that the determinant of $L$ is zero?

Comment: $h^{\mu \nu}$ is, in a sense, the gauge field of the translation group, so the coordinate transformation route should be equivalent. Non-uniqueness of $h^{\mu \nu}$ would spoil the invertibility, so I would say yes, it should imply zero determinant of $L$.

Comment: Is there any source on how to prove that the determinant of $L$ is zero?

Comment: Fourier transform the equation, then calculate the determinant. In $L$, it simply amounts to changing $\partial_\mu \rightarrow -i k_\mu$. I can't recall any source, but the calculation is pretty standard in QFT books, should be in the QED section where you go from the field equations and try to find the propagator.

Comment: P.S. You probably won't have to actually calculate the determinant, there should be an obvious eigenvector with zero eigenvalue, which would prove the vanishing of the determinant.